# override sbt dependency resolving mechanism (and prevent jar hell)

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, dependency-management

we have a large multi-project with many modules we build using sbt. turns out we have many issues regarding unwanted jars that get packaged. as a first step to deal with the problem, we have created a "global map" of used artifacts which is defined as follows:

`project/Build.scala`:

```
type PartialFunction2[-T1,-T2,+R] = PartialFunction[Tuple2[T1,T2],R]

lazy val dependenciesManager = settingKey[PartialFunction2[String, String, ModuleID]]("a setting containing versions for dependencies. if we only use it to declare dependencies, we can avoid a lot of version collisions.")
```

`build.sbt` in root:

```
dependenciesManager in Global := {
  case ("ch.qos.logback","logback-classic")  => "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.1"
  case ("com.typesafe","config")             => "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.0"
  case ("com.typesafe","scalalogging-slf4j") => "com.typesafe" %% "scalalogging-slf4j" % "1.1.0"
  case ("com.typesafe.akka",art)             => "com.typesafe.akka" %% art % "2.2.4"
  case ("com.typesafe.play", art)            => "com.typesafe.play" %% art % "2.2.3"
  ...
}
```

this allowed us to use in any module own `build.sbt` file the following syntax:

```
libraryDependencies <++= (dependenciesManager)(dm => Seq(
  dm("com.typesafe.akka","akka-cluster"),
  dm("com.typesafe.akka","akka-contrib"),
  dm("com.typesafe.play","play"),
  dm("ch.qos.logback","logback-classic")
))
```

which does not mention dependencies version.
but, since transitive dependencies still cause problems, it only solved part of the problems.

so I was thinking, what if, i could somehow define a dependencies map like the one above, which the resolving mechanism of sbt will "go through it" and it might change the dependency asked.

for instance, let's say i'm using `logback` with `slf4j-api`, i would'nt want a transitive dependency of `log4j` or `commons-logging` to be added to classpath, but rather a bridge like `jcl-over-slf4j` instead. a map like the one above could solve that.
also, different versions would not be loaded. and any artifact that may have changed it's name (like `google-collections` which is now called `guava` or `org.jboss.netty` groupID which was changed to `io.netty`) won't be an issue.

of course, whenever the dependency given is not the one asked for, a warning should be printed to screen, and whenever a new dependency is added, user should add it manually to the map with all it's transitive dependencies that are not there yet (or a match error would be thrown)

so my question is, is it possible to achieve something like that?
if so, how?

#### current thoughts on how to approach the problem:

- *modify the `ivyReport` task or the `update` task*: to my understanding, sbt creates an IvyReport xml file, that according to this file, ivy fetches the requested artifacts. I want to somehow modify the [update](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/sxr/sbt/Defaults.scala.html#sbt.Classpaths.updateTask) task, or the generated report, so the transitive dependencies would be the ones I want, and not the ones originally fetched.
- *use a solution similar to the one we already have*: only mark all the `ModuleID`s in the map as `intransitive()`, but (somehow) get their dependencies, and fetch them too (after mapping to the wanted artifacts)

Comment: opened a related issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1753

Answer (score 0):

I never used it, but you could try out [sbt-one-log](https://github.com/zavakid/sbt-one-log) and maybe use it as starting point for the other things you are trying to solve.

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for. the plugin simply modifies the library dependencies. i'd rather do it myself. what i'm looking for is complete control over dependencies. the log dependencies, was just an example...